# Explanation of the percentage value in scikit-learn PCA method

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

In scikit-learn, there is a method called [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html). This method takes a percentage parameter. [This site](https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-using-python-scikit-learn-e653f8989e60) explains this parameter as follows:

> Notice the code below has .95 for the number of components parameter.
>   It means that scikit-learn choose the minimum number of principal
>   components such that 95% of the variance is retained.

```
> from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
> # Make an instance of the Model 
> pca = PCA(.95)
```

I'm a bit in the dark about the interpretation of this explanation. Let's say the output of the PCA would be as follows:

- PC1 explains 70 % of the complete variance
- PC2 explains 15 % of the complete variance
- PC3 explains 10 % of the complete variance
- PC4 explains  4 % of the complete variance
- PC5 explains  1 % of the complete variance

Would the statement PCA(0.71) return PC1 and PC5 (as they both explain exactly 71 % of the variance) or would it return PC1 and PC2? What happens if I would like to retrieve 0.5 % of the variance, i.e. which PC would the statement PCA(0.005) return?

Comment: The idea is to maximize the variance in each dimension. So you will get PC1 and PC2 since PC2 > PC5.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Just to be clear about your answer: Would the statement PCA(0.01) thus also return PC1 and NOT PC5 even though PC5 explains exactly 1 % of the complete variance?

Comment: This is what I would expect and what is also hidden in the description. It does not extract the PC that matches your number but rather returns the first n PCs that have the amount of variance explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You touch a more general point that, although used all the time in practice, it is seldom explicitly mentioned, not even in tutorials and introductory expositions. Although such a question had never occurred to myself, it makes perfect sense from a beginner's point of view (beginners are usually free of some conventions, that more experienced practitioners take for granted and often they did not even notice them...).

Normally, when we select the no. of principal components (e.g. for dimensionality reduction, visualization etc), we select a number `k`, and implicitly it is meant "start from PC1 and continue *sequentially*, up to (and including) PCk". This is the principle, say, behind the [`preProcess`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/preProcess) function of the `caret` package in R (and arguably behind all functions performing similar tasks, in whatever software package).

In other words, and to the best of my knowledge at least, in cases such as the one you describe, we never choose PC's by *cherrypicking* (i.e. take PC2, PC4, and PC5, for example). Instead, we always choose a `k < n` (here `n=5`), and then we proceed to take *all the first* `k` PC's, i.e. starting from PC1 onward.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it thus be the best to simply ignore the "percentage parameter" and go for the "n_components" parameter of scikit-learn instead? Isn't there any official documentation concering the former? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Hagbard not necessarily, since you have clear in your mind what each one means (which you now have :), and that e.g. a `PCA(0.20)` in your example will give you just PC1... Unfortunately I don't know of any other resources in the topic...

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) says the below about the case where `0 < n_components < 1`:

> if `0 < n_components < 1` and svd_solver == 'full',
>
> select the number
>       of components such that the amount of variance that needs to be
>       explained is greater than the percentage specified by n_components.

It'd be more clear for you if it was mentioned like:

> if `0 < n_components < 1` and svd_solver == 'full',
>
> select the minimum number of components from the sorted list (descending order)
>   according to their respective explained variance values such that the amount of
>   variance that needs to be explained is greater than the percentage specified by n_components

so that there won't be an ambiguity.

Following that:

`PCA(0.71)` would return PC1 and PC2

`PCA(0.005)`-(an unlikely case) would return PC1